# How to get sqlite from databases folder in device?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello i had implemented this code [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

It takes my db from assets folder and copy it in databases folder into device. Now how could i get that databse from my device ?

or to get is just possible if my device is rooted or even then it's can't be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"currentDBPath" contains the path of the DB. You can copy it as a file and save it some where else using the following steps.

```
String currentDBPath = "/data/"+getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/databases/db_name";

FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel(); // source
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel(); // destination
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size()); // to copy from source to destination
src.close();
dst.close();
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `File srcFile = getDatabasePath("db_name");`

Comment: @Waqas no, this works for me... I am using it in my application.

Comment: @SheSmile did you create one first?

Comment: @Pallavi yes, i figure it out, it has to be 

        `"/data/data/"+getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/databases/wifiTable.db"`
it works for me if two data folder ;)